# Sharepoint Online - Hosted App Model App keeps disappearing

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

We have a sharepoint online site, with a VERY simple SharePoint Hosted App Model app. However, overthe past week ( and we have not updated it in +5 months) , it keeps disappearing from the site.

1. Gone from Pages that are using it ( App part is simply gone )
2. Gone from App Parts ( I tried to re-add it to the page, and its not available )
3. Seems to be installed, however.
4. Fix ? - If I reinstall it it works, but a day later, its gone again.

The app is simple and only has 2 javascript files in it, no server side code.

Googling has only turned up 1 other post on [social.msdn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/071c7a58-cbf8-46b8-8e00-c7a2ca4fa090/sharepoint-hosted-app-part-disappeared?forum=appsforsharepoint), so of course no answer there.

I could also not find any reported issues about this from microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

It seems issue is occuring when the recycle bin cleanup kicks in (30/90 days), try removing the app from 1st and 2nd stage recycle bin before reinstalling, it should not occur. You need to do this everytime you reinstall.